# Resetting IE 8 browser script

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to find a way to **reset the browser settings in IE 8 (XP & Win 7)** by using a script. I am a helpdesk tech and today I had to do this 20 times plus and I figured it's a simple task that I can write a script.

So far I found the script below which does what I want it to do without checking the box "Delete personal settings" which I would like it to do

**RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults**

Also, I see different scripts but to be honest I am just starting to learn python so it all still seems foreign. If you guys can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.